# Is it okay to ask Allah to make the tv breaks?

Tags: dua

My dad all he does is watch tv. And I am concerned for him. Alhamdulillah he prays his salaah but he doesn’t go to masjid. And he just prays at home then watches tv. Is it okay to make dua that Allah breaks the tv???

Comment: ...............

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any harm in making any such Duas, until or unless you ask for a Dua to harm someone. I would suggest it would be much better if you try to talk him out of doing this. Try to talk to him one on one and try convincing him politely. That's all I can say for now.

Answer (score 0):

Common bro.. leave him alone... what does he watch in TV? Is he watches news, comedy and things alike which are void of haraam scenes.. then leave him alone.. just humbly ask him to come along with you to Masjidh for any one salah... and if he continues it.. then rest will be easy for him.. they have already worked hard their entire life and they are taking rest now.. its your turn now to take care of them..

Well I'll give you an idea to divert him from TV. Buy carrom board and bring your family to sit together and play it. Seriously once they sit for one time.. they gonna get addicted. Take them out for a dinner or a walk. Make comedy with them. Make them laugh. Hug them. Sit with them and ask about their childhood like how life was during their childhood.. what they did.. how was the world that time..

Regarding the dua. I don't think it is appropriate to ask Allah to break the TV. Because TV is not the problem. The mind is. A knife can be useful and at the same time harmful. Its the user who uses it. Now think if a situation where your TV really breaks. What do you think they are gonna do? If they have money, they will buy another one or if no money, then they will start using the smart phone too much.. stuff like YouTube... ads.. .  Netflix will land them it trouble... you can understand what I mean right?  Never force anyone to do Good.. especially in deen.. its gonna land them in serious problems...

Alhamdulillah. And Allah knows best..